# Scoreboard / test for one of multiple stacks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to test if a player has any dirt or sand on him, both with a count of 2. So I tested this command:

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dirt",Count:2b},{id:"minecraft:glass",Count:2b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:2b},{id:"minecraft:planks",Count:2b}]}
```

But the problem is that it will only give an output if you have all the items. I want it to give an output if it have 1 of the items with a count of 2.

If you can do this with scoreboard it would be better. But I haven't found out yet how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much everything command related in Minecraft is AND connected, not OR. That's because you can do OR connections with multiple commands. For example:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add hasItem {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dirt",Count:2b}]}
/scoreboard players tag @a add hasItem {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:glass",Count:2b}]}
/scoreboard players tag @a add hasItem {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:2b}]}
/scoreboard players tag @a add hasItem {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:planks",Count:2b}]}

/execute @a[tag=hasItem] ~ ~ ~ say hi
```